# How to suppress angle brackets around hyperlinks in RichEdit control

Tags: mfc, rtf, richedit

I'm using `CRichEditCtrl::StreamIn` to initialize the contents of a `RichEdit20W` control from an RTF file in a resource at runtime. The RTF text from the file:

... `blah {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "www.foo.com/bar"}}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1 www.foo.com/bar}}}\f0\fs24  blah` ...

I noticed a difference in behavior between Win XP and Win 7 (not sure about Vista):

In **Win XP** (link is displayed without any formatting, or surrounding brackets):

> ... blah www.foo.com/bar blah ...

In **Win 7** (link is displayed in blue, with underline, and surrounded by angle brackets):

> ... blah <www.foo.com/bar> blah ...

If I load the same document into WordPad or MS Word, the link is displayed (blue underlined text), *but without the surrounding brackets*.

I think WordPad uses the same control behind the scenes, so there must be some way to suppress this behavior. Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Answer (score 0):

Please share if found a solution. I am also facing the same problem.

I edited my rtf to remove hyperlink tag and kept the URL as normal text and set `EM_AUTOURLDETECT` as true. Richeedit identified the URL and hyperlink and handled the `EN_LINK` message in `WM_NOTIFY`.

Though may not be the solution to the actual problem.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that this is an OS difference, and that there's nothing that can be done about it. I'll be happy if someone can prove me incorrect. :-)